# qformat for parts in exam?

Tags: formatting, exam

In the exam package I would like to customize `\part` header. I know I can change the `\qformat` for questions, but I didn't find any similar command for parts.

In my case my parts looks like:

```
(a) (5 points) Foobar
```

The double parenthesis are not really elegant. I would rather prefer to put the points at the end:

```
(a) Foobar [5 points]
```

Is it possible do to this?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\noaddpoints
\titledquestion{Foo}[\totalpoints]
\addpoints    
\begin{parts}
\part[42] Foobar
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small but complete example document that generates the output you show? That would make it easier to start on changing the appearance of the header without first needing to recreate the document.

Comment: I've added a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

To change the parentheses into brackets, you can use the command `\bracketedpoints`.

As to where the points are placed, you have the following options (as far as I can tell, what you are asking for is not quite possible):

- As it is now
- Right margin at the beginning of the part (use `\pointsinrightmargin`)
- Left margin at the beginning of the part (use `\pointsinleftmargin`)
- Right margin after the part question
- Right margin after the part question on the line below the question

For the last two:
Add `\pointsdroppedatright` before your question.
For the first case, add `\droppoints` at the end of your question. For the second case, add the same command but with a blank line between the question and the command.

I hope this was helpful.